# How to see Perfmon graphs in HTML Dashboard results in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

in JMeter Html reports, the Perfmon metrics are not included. how to add the CPU, Memory, Network and Disk graphs to those Apache JMeter Dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

There is no each "switch" to add those, I can think of the following workaround:

1. Fetch Individual metrics using i.e. [TCP Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-tcp-protocol-services-jmeter) from the [PerfMon Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent#using-server-agent-with-other-applications)
2. Store them into [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
3. Plot the variables on the custom charts as it's described in [Generating customs graphs over time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs) JMeter user manual entry

Comment: so that TCP sampler should be in the same thread group as load samplers? If tester has 1000 threads, metrics will be queried in 1000 threads too.

Comment: I didn't tell anywhere that it should be in the same thread group